# Product translated URL for iframe purposes

Tags: magento-1.9, url, localisation, iframe

I am working on a 1.9.x version of Magento, I've just translated the products of my catalog for a PT-BR language and I was needing the products URLs in order to insert them on a iframe of a specific website in portuguese. Even though rewriting the url (to distinguish the italian version from the portuguese one), when I copy and paste the url of the portuguese product and insert on the code of the iframe of the website mentioned before, the iframe shows a 404 error.

Is there something I could be doing to exhibit this product in portuguese on the iframe? Because by now I can only show the italian (default) version and only when the user adds the product to the shopping cart it reveals the language window so he/she can select the PT and then the product could be visualized in portuguese. But not in the step before.

Answer (score -1):

Solved - i just added the ?___store=portoghese&___from_store=portoghese line after the default link! :)